# Elasticsearch: empty hits array although total is greater than 0

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

For the following query

```
    {
        index: i,
        from: 0,
        size: 10,
        body: {
            query: {
                filtered: {
                    query: {
                        term: { "si" : si}
                    }
                }                       
            }
        }               
    }
```

I get returned the following answer

```
    {
      "took": 1,
      "timed_out": false,
      "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "failed": 0
      },
      "hits": {
        "total": 4,
        "max_score": 5.1108737,
        "hits": [

        ]
      }
    }
```

I found this post on the same topic https://discuss.elastic.co/t/hits-hits-array-empty-even-thought-total-1/19930 but still don't understand, how to solve my problem, since I thought

```
from: 1
```

would according to his solution solve the issue.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What happens if you remove `index: i` and add `_source: true`?

Comment: Then the hits array seems to always contain all hits within all indices for this si value (this can add up to more than 100 hits).

Comment: Can you show how you are sending your query?

Comment: I use node to send the query request. The code looks like this:
`client.search(query_exactly_as_in_my_question_above).then(function(resp) { }` the `resp` object contains the answer I posted above

Comment: Oh, you're using the JS client. Then leave `index: i` (sorry about that) and just include `_source: true`

Comment: I included `_source: true`, so the head of the query looks like this `{index: i, _source: true, from: 0, size: 10, body: {...`, but the answer still has an empty hits-array while the `total` value is always bigger than 0.

Comment: How do you print out the response?

Comment: I use `JSON.stringify(resp)`, and also check for: `resp.hits.hits.length == 0` is `true` and `resp.hits.hits[0]` is `undefined`.

Comment: Also It just started returning a correct hits array, just every now and then. So now sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't

Comment: Ok, can you tell if you consistently see results when executing this: `curl -XPOST localhost:9200/your_index/_search -d '{"from":0,"size":10,"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"term":{"si":si}}}}}'` (just replace `your_index` and `si` appropriately)

Comment: Since I work in a closed system I can only do an XPOST request using node. I made a node file, doing only this one request and it always returns the correct data and a filled hits array. And now the query within my working system is also always returning full hits arrays, without having changed anything in that code. So I can't reproduce the error. I can just hope it stays that way.

Comment: If I can reproduce the problem or find any solutions, I will post them!

Answer (score 1):

```
By default, elasticsearch starts showing its  Query results from pageNum as 0 and the search query we define generally start from pageNum as 1.
Ensure that if you are setting the pageNum, it is set to 0 in case you have the resultset within the pageSize limit.
```

I was facing the same issue where I could see total_hits as 1 with empty array being returned. I found that I was setting the default pageNum to 1 ,however elasticsearch starts it from 0 and hence was returning the second page when queried with pageNum as 1